# Eclipse PDT + PHP 8 + Xdebug 3 + Vagrant. Debugging is not working

Tags: php, eclipse, vagrant, xdebug

I'm trying to make this setup work with no success for debugging. I have this Xdebug configuration in a Vagrant box with PHP 8 but I can't debug with Eclipse PDT... Can anybody help or point to the right direction?

[image: screen1 xdebug]

[image: screen2 xdebug]

[image: screen3 xdebug]

Answer (score 1):

The solution was setup xdebug.clienthost to my Windows Machine local network, where eclipse is installed. So I did vagrant ssh, then edit the 20-xdebug.ini located at

/etc/php(the version you are using)/fpm/conf.d and added the line

xdebug.client_host =192.168.1.49

notice that your xdebug.client_port must be 9003 also

of course this is my ip of my laptop in my local network you have to figure out yours and make it fixed if you are behind a dhcp router.

Then I did a vagrant reload.

Then in Eclipse I setup the xdebug preferences to listen the 9003 port, stop the first line and prompt for remote connection.

And in firefox I installed the xdebug helper and choose "debug" before loading the page.